# Access a service from a Job in Vapor 3

Tags: swift, client-server, vapor, server-side-swift

I'm very new to Vapor and server-side swift, with a background in iOS development (6 years developing apps). I'm trying to build a simple API for device management which amongst other things includes a "job" (Timer whatever you want to call it) which checks every hour or so for the last time a device "Checked In".

To do this I've setup the Jobs package, however I'm struggling to work out how I can access a service ([Ferno](https://github.com/vapor-community/ferno)) to hit my Firebase Realtime database to get info about when devices last logged in. It seems that according to the docs you need an implementer of `Container` to create/access a `Service` but there doesn't seem to be any kind of global container I can use.

Should I be attempting to create my own `Request` just to access a `Ferno` service? Or is there a way I can access the global `app`?

The below is what I have so far, but what I'm doing seems horribly wrong! Surely there must be a way to achieve this?

```
Jobs.add(interval: (60*30).seconds) { [weak devicesController] in
    devicesController?.checkForNotSeenDevices()
}
```

```
func checkForNotSeenDevices() throws {

    let client = try app(.detect()).make(FernoClient.self)
    client.ferno.retrieve(req: ???, queryItems: [], appendedPath: ["devices"])
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've struggled with Ferno too.

Inside boot.swift, use global app as container for ferno client and request.

```
    let client = try! app.make(FernoClient.self)
    let request = Request(using: app)
```

Now your client is ready for Database Actions, example post action.Which can be repeated each time using your own Jobs.

```
    let inputData = try! client.ferno.overwrite(req: request, appendedPath: ["users/john"], body: yourOwnContentModel)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me because it re-initialises the app each time my job is called and causes issues with my timer setup (namely each time it's called it adds a new `Job`)

Answer (score 2):

To do scheduled tasks, better use `scheduleRepeatedTask` on an `EventLoop`. You could e.g. call this inside your `boot.swift`:

```swift
app.eventLoop.scheduleRepeatedTask(initialDelay: .seconds(0), delay: .minutes(30)) { _ in
    let client = try app.make(FernoClient.self)
    let request = Request(using: app)
    client.ferno.retrieve(req: request, queryItems: [], appendedPath: ["devices"])
}
```

Actually `FernoClient().client.retrieve` doesn't really need a `Request`, but a `Worker`. Unfortunately, the library explicitly states `Request`, so you need to to this workaround. You could make a PR to `Ferno` and replace `Request` by `Worker`, if I didn't miss anything here. Then you could just call it like this:

```swift
client.ferno.retrieve(worker: app, queryItems: [], appendedPath: ["devices"])
```

Comment: I actually ended up still using `jobs` here, but thanks for the advice to use this in `boot.swift`!